# how to same the output value to respective variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix

the variables line,word,char dont get value!

```
line= wc -l < $*
word= wc -w < $*
char= wc -m < $*
echo "Number of characters in test.txt is $char"
echo "Number of words in test.txt is $word"
echo "Number of lines in test.txt is $line"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the command in `$()`:

```
line=$(wc -l < $1)
```

Comment: i am taking input from a file idk if that is making difference but the output values are wrong

Comment: @HimanshuSharma Updated the answer. Does that work for you?